# I want media query only for Ipad safari browser that does not affect Ipad chrome browser

Tags: html, css

```
    @media only screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (orientation: portrait) {
   .faculty-img_1 {
        top: 48px;
    }
}
```

This is the css I used which affects both the browser

Comment: You need something to detect browsers/OS and put a class in the html

Comment: CSS-only browser detection is a bit of a nightmare, you would have a much easier time if you can use JS and add e.g. a ".safari" class to the body, then base your styles on that.